# Scene Builder Include Crash

Tags: javafx, custom-controls, scenebuilder

I recently discovered Scene Builder and it seems great. However as soon as I try to include any custom component I've made it crashes. I've been looking around and I get the feeling that Scene Builder has weird problems like this. What is up with that? Is there a way around this? Are there any other tools that are better?

I've heard of importing jars but what if I want to use components within a single project? It seems like a lot of work to be making separate jars for every single component that I want to reuse.

I am using Eclipse Oxygen, Java 9 and Scene Builder 9. I've tried it on two different computers now with the exact same issues.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: There was a filed bug related to including [FXML files](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/issues/158/including-fxml-fails-with-npe). Is this your case? It has been already fixed, and it will be available in the next release. You can either fork and build the [project](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder) yourself, or you can edit the FXML file and manually do the include. After that Scene Builder will be able to open it.

Comment: Thanks, I will try my best to make it work.

Comment: It works! Thank you for helping me. Now I just need to figure out how to structure my program with several custom nodes.